# SVN diff with beyond compare 4 result in "file not found" error, Mac OS High Sierra

Tags: svn, macos-high-sierra, beyondcompare, beyondcompare4

I have install beyond compare and followed the official technic support to configure it with svn:

http://www.scootersoftware.com/support.php?zz=kb_vcs_osx

However, when I run the following command:
svn diff -c 53030 .

To show all changes made to the revision 53030, I got the following command line error output:

```
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.1.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:50: Error: unsupported compressor 8
```

/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.1.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Resources/Exceptions.plist'
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.1.1/Common/ChunkCompression.cpp:50: Error: unsupported compressor 8
/BuildRoot/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/AppleFSCompression/AppleFSCompression-96.1.1/Libraries/CompressData/CompressData.c:353: Error: Unknown compression scheme encountered for file '/System/Library/CoreServices/CoreTypes.bundle/Contents/Library/AppExceptions.bundle/Exceptions.plist'

And also, the beyond compare gui launched with errors, showing the following files not found:

```
/var/folders/2t/zb3hw5b57yb77y58sshrxgx00000gn/T/svn-Flmvf1
```

/var/folders/2t/zb3hw5b57yb77y58sshrxgx00000gn/T/svn-BX0hCF

I suspect svn should have created the above 2 temporary files, corresponding to the versions before and after the change committed at 53030, and BC tries to load them and display.

However when I checked the folder:
/var/folders/2t/zb3hw5b57yb77y58sshrxgx00000gn/T
These 2 files are NOT created.

Anyone knows how to solve this?

Beyond Compare v4.2.3
Mac OS High Sierra 10.13.1

Answer (score 1):

The "Unknown compression scheme encountered for file" errors are a compatibility issue between Beyond Compare and macOS 10.13. Although messages are displayed to the terminal, it should still work for diffs of single files. The bug should be fixed in the next release of Beyond Compare, version 4.2.4.

Diffing multiple files in a folder (svn diff) doesn't appear to work correctly using the instructions on the page you linked. Diffing individual files (svn diff file.ext) should work correctly if you follow the instructions on the page you linked.

Comment: Can confirm that upgrading from 4.2.3 to 4.2.6 fixed this for me on macos 10.13.6.